# Where are dokku persistent storage files actually stored on a Mac host machine?

Tags: django, docker, macos, persistence, dokku

Where are [dokku persistent storage](https://dokku.com/docs/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/) files actually stored on a host machine? The documentation says the location is `/var/lib/dokku/data/storage/` - but that directory doesn't even exist on my macos m2 host machine - not even `/var/lib/dokku/` exists.  Docker is installed via Docker Desktop.

Whilst I can successfully map a container directory to dokku persistent storage location:

```
dokku storage:ensure-directory myapp
dokku storage:mount myapp /var/lib/dokku/data/storage/myapp:/code/media
dokku ps:restart myapp
```

and writing files to `/code/media/` works, and the files are persisted, and `/code/media/` is shown to be a mount point to the host's `/var/lib/dokku/data/storage/myapp` dir in Docker Desktop's view of the container - when I actually look at that host location, it doesn't exist! e.g.

```
ls /var/lib/dokku/data/storage/myapp
No such file or directory
```

Despite this, the solution works and files written to the `/code/media` directory persist between container re-creations, so they must be kept somewhere. I can't see any related volumes. The only clue is that `/var/lib/dokku/data/storage/myapp` exists inside the `myapp` container, albeit with no files in it. Note, my dokku app `myapp` is a Django app deployed via a Dockerfile (since buildpacks don't work on ARM).